# Bound AngularJS template not changing in angular datatable

Tags: angularjs, angular-datatables

I am using angular data table from below link

http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/bindAngularDirective

I am using the defer rending concept here.

I have 2 button

1. Active (Show when user status is 1)
2. Inactive (Show when user status is 0)

As 2 way data binding not working here. I am unable to show Inactive button after clicking on active & viceversa

Below is my code

```
 $scope.setCustomers = function (s, dto, dtc, f, c, h, t) {
    s.dtInstance = {};
    s.actions = {};
    //dtOptions - Makes the ajax request to get the customer records, also builds the buttons to copy,csv,excel..etc
    s.dtOptions = dto.fromSource('customers/showCustomers.json')
            .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
            .withDisplayLength(25)
            .withOption('createdRow', createdRow)
            .withDOM('<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp').withDisplayLength(25);

    // dtColumns - Builds the columns and renders the rows for each column
    s.dtColumns = [
        dtc.newColumn('name').withTitle('Name'),
        dtc.newColumn('email').withTitle('Email'),
        dtc.newColumn('phone').withTitle('Phone'),
        dtc.newColumn('status').withTitle('Status')
                .renderWith(function (data) {
                    return  "<div style=text-align:center;>" + (data == 1 ? 'Accepted' : data == 2 ? 'Declined' : 'Pending') + "</div>";
                }),
        dtc.newColumn(null).withTitle('Actions').notSortable()
                .renderWith(actionsHtml)
    ];
    function createdRow(row, data, dataIndex) {
        c(angular.element(row).contents())(s);
    }
    function actionsHtml(data, type, full, meta) {
        s.actions[data.id] = data;
        var actions = '<button ladda="loadingDemo' + data.customer_id + '" class="ladda-button ladda-button-demo btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-style="zoom-in" ng-click="resetPassword(actions[' + data.id + '])" uib-tooltip="Reset Password" tooltip-placement="top"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></button>&nbsp;'
                + '<a href="#/customers/viewBalance/' + data.unique_id + "/" + data.customer_id + '" ><button class="btn btn-info btn-xs" uib-tooltip="Transaction History" tooltip-placement="top"><i class="fa fa-money"></i></button></a>&nbsp;'
                + '<a href="#/invoices/view-invoice/' + data.unique_id + '" ><button class="btn btn-info btn-xs" uib-tooltip="View Orders"><i class="fa fa-files-o"></i></button></a>&nbsp;'
                + '<a href="#/customers/view-customer/' + data.uniq_id + '" ><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" tooltip-placement="top" uib-tooltip="View Profile"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button></a>&nbsp;'
                + '<a href="#/customers/add-customer/step-one/' + data.uniq_id + '" ><button class="btn btn-success btn-xs" tooltip-placement="top" uib-tooltip="Edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button></a>&nbsp;';
        if (data.is_active == 1) {
            actions += '<button class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-is_active="' + data.is_active + '" ng-click="setStatus(actions[' + data.id + '])" tooltip-placement="top" uib-tooltip="Inactive"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>&nbsp;';
        } else {
            actions += '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"  data-is_active="' + data.is_active + '" ng-click="setStatus(actions[' + data.id + '])" tooltip-placement="top" uib-tooltip="Active"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i></button>&nbsp;';
        }

        return actions;
    }
}
$scope.setCustomers($scope, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder, $filter, $compile, $http, toaster);
```

Thanks

Comment: Use the [ngShow/ngHide directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) to change the buttons. The template is only compiled once when the cell is loaded.